# R: How to replace only particular strings in a dataframe column

Tags: r, stringr

I have a dataframe column which has values like Americ0,Indi0,Data 2.0...
While doing the data cleaning I am supposed to replace "0" with "an"

```
df$column <- lapply(df$column, function(x){
  str_replace(x,"0","an")

})
```

I am using the above code to replace *0* with "an" which is working as expected. The problem now is there are certain values in df$column which are not to be replaced like the value *Data 2.0* .Appreciate if someone can help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a `str_replace` from `stringr`,Assuming x is df$column:

```
library(stringr)
x <- c("Americ0","Indi0","Data 2.0")
str_replace(x,"([:alpha:]+)(0)","\\1an")
```

Or, using baseR

```
gsub("([[:alpha:]]+)(0)","\\1an",x)
```

**Output:**

```
> str_replace(x,"([:alpha:]+)(0)","\\1an")
[1] "American" "Indian"   "Data 2.0"


> gsub("([[:alpha:]]+)(0)","\\1an",x)
[1] "American" "Indian"   "Data 2.0"
```

Inside parenthesis , the items getting captured are called captured group, so I captured all the alphabets more than one into a capture group 1, Hence in this case 2.0 would not get selected.

From documentation:

> [:alpha:] Alphabetic characters: [:lower:] and [:upper:].

For more you can search `?regex` on your console

Comment: I have issues while working with the data starting with 0 ex: 0imal..(Animal). I tried replacing + with ?  but then 2.0 is getting changed. Any suggestions??

Comment: @HariKrishnaReddy : use 
`str_replace(x,"([:alpha:]+)(0)|^0","\\1an")` OR 
`gsub("([[:alpha:]]+)(0)|^0","\\1an",x)` , it should work. please request you to ask a generic question rather than keep changing your question, that is why in SO we ask for reproducible example. Thanks

Comment: Thanks once again for helping out.. will keep in mind going forward..:)

Comment: @HariKrishnaReddy,  thanks, you can use `tools::toTitleCase(gsub("([[:alpha:]]+)(0)|^(0)","\\1an",x,perl=T))` to make everything in title case  , you need to install `tools` incase if it not there in your r installation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you would do this without having some sort of rule on which you want/do not want to replace like maybe don't replace if 0 is at the beginning, or if 0 occurs in this set of strings.

With your current setup you could probably do something like this (assuming only "Data 2.0" is something you want to skip)

```
df <- as.data.frame(c("Americ0","Indi0","Data 2.0"))
colnames(df)[1] = "column"

do_not_replace <- c("Data 2.0")

df$column <- lapply(df$column, function(x) {
  if(x %in% do_not_replace) {
    x
  } else str_replace(x, "0", "an")
})
```